# How to write dynamic Sql query

Tags: sql, dynamic

I have a table with 2 columns. If row contains value only for column 1, then i need to perform action a. If it has value for both columns, i need to perform action b, if row has only column 2, i need to perform action action 3. How to write SQL for this

Comment: What database?  Is the action you want perform? A command/query or something on the app side?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try creating a function returning table , with all your conditions met. maintain a table variable ( say @tab1 ) inside steps, insert interim values to this table ( or append ) ,  and finally return that variable.

this way you may use this function inside sql queries

Answer (score 0):

If by "action" you mean "set a value in a column in the result set", then you want a `case` expression:

```
select (case when col1 is not null and col2 is null then 'a'
             when col1 is not null and col2 is not null then 'b'
             when col1 is null and col2 is not null then 'c'
        end)
from t;
```